# close port 10180

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, port

This morning I ran zenmap against our domain controller (windows 2003 server) and found an unknown open port

Discovered open port 10180/tcp on 192.xxx.xxx.xxx

Through various google searches I found it is commonly used as a quickbooks database port which shows ways to open the port but no way to close it. i found this [site](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2009/04/21/installing-quickbooks-2008-on-sbs-2008.aspx) that shows how to open it with windows firewall but when I ran the instructions to close the port it was not visible as an open port.

I'm taking the tried and true, close the port and see who yells approach on this one, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worry about the process opening the port, not the port itself.  Does it show up in the output of `netstat -abn`?

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is running on the port currently.